# How Gradle tasks inline configuration works under the hood ?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to understand how gradle build script is interpreted under the hood.

I get that the entire build script delegates to the project object, so when we type

```
task taskName
```

we are executing a function defined in the project object with task as name  and taking a string parameter.

What is weird for me is the inline configuration of the task :

```
taskName.description = "Description of the task"
taskName.group = "Group of the task"
```

How this really works in the level of project object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html, the first "Properties" section.

Here are the useful bits with some of the details removed:

> A project has 5 property 'scopes', which it searches for properties. The scopes are:
>
> - The Project object itself.
> - The extra properties of the project.
> - The extensions added to the project by the plugins.
> - The tasks of the project.
>
> The extra properties and convention properties inherited from the project's parent, recursively up to the root project. The properties of this scope are read-only.
>
> When reading a property, the project searches the above scopes in order, and returns the value from the first scope it finds the property in. If not found, an exception is thrown.

In your example, `taskName.description = "..."` means that Gradle looks up `taskName` as a method on `Project`, as an extra property, as an extension and then it finds a task with that name. Then you're just calling `setDescription` on a regular `Task` object.

The magic happens in [`Project.property()`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0b9cb4429513297e03965b0578607d10a2a1fcdf/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProject.java#L991) using a `ExtensibleDynamicObject` configured like so:
https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/0b9cb4429513297e03965b0578607d10a2a1fcdf/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProject.java#L226-L230

Comment: Thank you for your response which i found very helpful, however there is no description about what happen exactly between the phase of declaring a new task and the phase of accessing it as a property !

I would like to know how this is possible under the hood, how based on a call to a function that create a new task we  are then able to access this task as a property ?

Thank you again.

Comment: Could it be that the task is added as a dynamic property of the project object ?

Comment: When you create a task, it gets added to the task list.  That's the same task list that's checked when looking for something that's not a method on Project, an extra property or an extension.  This all happens as part of the dynamic look-up of properties.